# using the map for getting the property to disable or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the javascript. In this ,

I have following scenario.

```
let bgmap = {
  'Pre': ['clo', 'buy', 'Pre'],
  'buy': ['clo','buy'],
  'clo': ['clo'],
}
```

Now, In this Map I am getting the current value , `it can be either Pre, clo or buy.` I have a dropdown menu which I want to disable the options . `The options are pre, clo, buy.`

Now, Here,

```
If currentValue is `Pre` then all three will enabled.
If currentValue is 'buy' then clo and buy will be enabled.
If currentValue is clo the only clo will be enabled.
```

Now, In this
I have implemented the following.

```
const validateStatus = (current)=> {
    return current.includes(bgmap[current]);
}
```

Now, I am calling this

```
disabled={validateStatus(current)}
```

But here, my solution is not working. Every time it is either enabling or disabling. Can any one help me with this ?

In my react code -

```
   {bs &&
            bs.map((status, index) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={status.Id}
                value={status.Value}
                disabled={validateStatus(status.Value)}
                classes={{
                  selected: css.selected
                }}
                >
                {status.Description}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The two `current` in your handler function may have different meaning

Comment: the current value can be 'Pre' or 'buy', or 'clo'

Comment: Then you may need `bgmap[current].includes(someOtherValue)`

Comment: `const validateStatus = (current)=> {
    return bgmap[current].includes(current);
}`

Comment: Hey I used this but now it is lets say its current is clo then it is enabling the. other two and disabling the clo , but it should have reverse , I mean clo should be enabled and other two will be disabled.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working.

Comment: @Rayon I updated the code of react where I am iterating this, I mean it is taking I guess last value

Answer (score 0):

Properties of object - used

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let bgmap = {
  'Pre': ['clo', 'buy', 'Pre'],
  'buy': ['clo','buy'],
  'clo': ['clo'],
};

const validateStatus = (current)=> {
    return bgmap.hasOwnProperty(current) ? bgmap[current] : Object.values(bgmap)[0];
}
let current = 'Pre'; // check the code viva assigning all diff values
console.log(validateStatus(current));
```